# Short Circuit Linq for (Count > 1)

Tags: c#, linq

One of the advantages of `linq.Any()` is that it short Circuits once the first result is returned, so is O(1) not O(n).

If I want to check if `Linq.Count() > n` where `n` > 1, what is the optimal way to short circuit the expression, so that it doesn't significantly slow things down when Linq.Count() is close to n, but speeds things up when Linq.Count() is large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used

```
Linq.Skip(n).Any();
```

If you know that no elements are null, you could use

```
Linq.ElementAtOrDefault(n) != null
```

Although I don't know if there would be any speed advantage to this.

Comment: Note that in many cases (`Linq` is `IQueryable`, is array, list or any other `ICollection`) - this will be slower than `Count() > n`, or just won't work.

Comment: @Evk Why wouldn't it work if the source is IQueryable?

Comment: @Evk As IQueryable is converted to a Sql query, where the count is stored without having to enumerate the rows.

Comment: @Magnus it might or might not work, depending on provider. For example, Entity Framework provider has no idea how to translate `ElementAtOrDefault`. And `Skip()` should always be preceeded by `OrderBy`, so won't work as provided either.

Comment: @Evk: it depends: if  we ask, say, `AtLeast(2)` for `IQueryable` while the `Count() == 123456789` it can well be very exp[ensive for server to compute the  actual count; the same for collections like `LinkedList`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I agree, I should have said "this might be slower". That's exactly my point - it depends on various factors whether method mentioned in answer worth using and will be an improvement or not.

Comment: @Evk since the op is talking about time complexity and short circuiting I assume it is linq 2 objects this question is about.

Answer (score 3):

You could always write it as an extension

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool HasAtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int n)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach(var item in enumerable)
        {
          if(++i == n)
              return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/IMIJ79900